# When I make a project reference in Visual Studio, do I then have to include the DLLs for those projects when I deploy?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, dll

I have a console application and two class library projects.

The console application has to project references to the class library projects.

When I build, it generates DLLs for these two projects.  Do I have to include these with my console applications exe file?  Is there a way I can make it so I don't have to include these 2 dlls?

Ideally, I'd like to have a single exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must include any referenced assemblies as they are dependencies of your application.

That being said, however, Microsoft offers a tool called [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) that will allow you combine the dependency assemblies with your executable to create one, all-inclusive, executable assembly that you can ship to customers.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the assemblies into one, using [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx), otherwise you'll have to deploy the exe file and the dlls.
e.g. you can run a command like

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:MyProg.exe Program.exe ClassLib1.dll ClassLib.dll
```

Visual Studio provides no built-in way to do this, so you'd have to run the above command manually,as a Post Build event, or add it manually to your .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish by selecting your references and setting the "Copy Local" property to false.

Comment: That will copy the .dlls into (e.g.) the Debug/ output folder, you'd still have to ship the dlls and the exe when distributing  the app.

Comment: That's how I do it for my binary WinForms applications.

Comment: @nos: That's not how it behaves for me. Maybe I'm just a freak of nature but I have a WinForms executable with 8 references in the local projects, all set Copy Local to "false". I only deploy the .exe and it works like a charm.

Comment: That is because it embeds this information into the project.
This can happen if you define a connection string to your application instead of using the app.config / web.config file.

Comment: @JonH: Give it a try. If you have config information you still need to ship a separate config (but this can be worked around using compiled .resx files). I just verified it because you people have me thinking I'm crazy. I just shipped an exe with a config to a server that has never even seen this application (I thought maybe my success was masked by files in the GAC, but it wasn't), and it worked splendidly.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: I do not believe this is true. It is not consistent with documentation and I cannot duplicate this. I get the exception System.TypeInitializationException because of the missing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with ILMerge and make sure you understand the performance implications of going this route.